# How do I loop through arrays within arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to dynamically create a series of bootstrap cards with returned AJAX data. The AJAX request brings back 12 arrays (see [screenshot](https://ibb.co/M1Wdghz)) but when I try to loop through them and put them on cards only 1 array gets put on all twelve cards (See [screenshot](https://ibb.co/Mffnpp4))

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong with my loop but hoping someone can help out.

Here is the JS code (sorry about the super long line for the card creation - any advice on how to shorten that would be appreciated).

Below is a reproducible example (the actual data variable is filled by the AJAX call in my code), and here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ud198nm3/42/):

```
data = [["The Old Milk Bar", "  144 Dundas Street, Thornbury", "Lorem Ipsum"], ["Little Henri", "  848  High Street, Thornbury", 'Lorem Ipsum'], ["Northern Soul", "  843 High Street, Thornbury", "Lorem Ipsum"]]

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    console.log('page is fully loaded');
    test(data)
    });
    
const test = function(data) {
  console.log(data)
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var results = JSON.stringify(data).split('"');
    var cafeName = results[1].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9éè ]/g, "");
    console.log(cafeName)
    var cafeAddress = results[3].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9éè ]/g, "") + "," + results[2].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9éè ]/g, "");
    console.log(cafeAddress)
    var cafeDescription = results[5];
    console.log(cafeDescription)
    $(".venue-name").html(cafeName);
    $(".venue-address").html(cafeAddress);
    $(".venue-description").html(cafeDescription);
    $(".share").html('<i class="fas fa-share-alt"></i>');
    $(".venue-options").html('<i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>');
    var myCol = $('<div id="col"></div>');
    var myPanel = $(
      '<div class="card-group"><div class="card card-block m-3 overflow-auto" style="width: 18rem;"><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title venue-name"></h5><h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted venue-address"></h6><div class="dropdown"><div class="venue-options" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></div><div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"><a id="share" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Share</a><a id="addToList" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Add to List</a></div></div><div class="venue-description"></div></div></div></div>'
    );
    myPanel.appendTo(myCol);
    myCol.appendTo('#cardList');
  };
}
```

Comment: You're making things much harder than they need to be. Just use `var cafeName = data[i][0];`

Comment: Did you notice that you never use `i` anywhere in the loop? What's the point of the loop if you don't use the iteration variable?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. For some reason using ``i`` wasn't getting the result. I tried your suggestion in the fiddle and had the same problem with the repeating item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `JSON.stringify()` and `split()`. You already have an array, you can access its elements directly.

When you do `$(".venue-name").html(cafeName)` you're setting the HTML of *all* elements with that class, not the card you're creating. In fact, it sets every one *except* the new one, because you don't add that until after those lines.

Instead, create `myPanel` first, and then set the HTML of the elements within that DIV. You can do this with `myPanel.find(".className")` or equivalently `$(".className", myPanel)`.

```js
data = [
  ["The Old Milk Bar", "  144 Dundas Street, Thornbury", "Lorem Ipsum"],
  ["Little Henri", "  848  High Street, Thornbury", 'Lorem Ipsum'],
  ["Northern Soul", "  843 High Street, Thornbury", "Lorem Ipsum"]
]

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  console.log('page is fully loaded');
  test(data)
});

const test = function(data) {
  console.log(data)
  data.forEach(([cafeName, cafeAddress, cafeDescription]) => {
    var myCol = $('<div id="col"></div>');
    var myPanel = $(
      `
      <div class="card-group">
        <div class="card card-block m-3 overflow-auto" style="width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title venue-name"></h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted venue-address"></h6>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <div class="venue-options" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></div>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"><a id="share" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Share</a><a id="addToList" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Add to List</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="venue-description"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>`
    );
    $(".venue-name", myPanel).html(cafeName);
    $(".venue-address", myPanel).html(cafeAddress);
    $(".venue-description", myPanel).html(cafeDescription);
    $(".share", myPanel).html('<i class="fas fa-share-alt"></i>', myPanel);
    $(".venue-options", myPanel).html('<i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>');
    myPanel.appendTo(myCol);
    myCol.appendTo('#cardList');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cardList"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the job, and I really appreciate the clear explanation. I know it isn't the OP but do you have advice on how to make the long line of code in ``myPanel`` more readable? Thanks again.

Comment: Use backticks instead of single quotes, then you can put newlines in it.